# object of abstract class type Rectangle is not allowed

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

This is my base class:

```
class Shape{
public:
Shape(){}
virtual double computeArea()=0;
virtual void expand(int f)=0'
virtual void display()=0;
}
```

This is my sub class:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape{
protected:
double width;
double height;
public:
Rectangle(){width = 0; length = 0;}
Rectangle(double w, double l){width = w; length = l}

double computeArea(){//code}
void expand(int f){//code}
void display(){//code}
}
```

Then, in main I try to do this:

```
Shape * s = new Rectangle();
```

And I keep getting "object of abstract class type "Rectangle" is not allowed"
I'm pretty sures I'm overloading the functions right... Please help.

Comment: Rectangle(double w, double l){width = w; length = l}
 is missing a ';' after length = l

Comment: Also, virtual void expand(int f)=0', replace single quote w/ ';'

Comment: Please post **actual** code - currently your member is called `height` not `length` so what you have posted will not compile

Comment: Just as a side note: In your derived class you override the methods of the base class, you do not overload them. It's called overloading when you define multiple functions with the same name but different argument types (within a single scope).

Answer (score 0):

We can't help if we can't be sure you are providing the exact code. Since I see *at least* two syntax errors here that would reject compilation **WELL BEFORE** warning about a missing vtable for a class.

```
virtual void expand(int f)=0'  // <- this ' should be a ;
```

and `void expand(int f){//code}` here there is no closing `}`. So this makes impossible to diagnose your problem.

The message *"object of abstract class type `Rectangle` is now allowed"* implies for sure that a pure virtual method is not overidden in the `Rectangle` class. Now if this happens because signature is different, or braces are unbalanced or whatever other strange syntax issue you may have introduced we can't know.

The only suggestion I can give is to add the `override` keyword after the method declaration in `Rectangle` to force verifying a proper override and have a more detailed error message. Eg:

```
void expand(int f) override { /* code */ }
```